# 'sudo ruby setup.rb' won't install Gems on Vagrant box

Tags: ruby, rubygems, vagrant

I'm new to using Vagrant and am trying to install Gems on it (Ruby is already installed). I am following the instructions [here](https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/ruby-for-newbies-working-with-gems--net-18977).

I've downloaded the latest version of Gems and extracted it. I have "cd'd" into that folder and have tried to run:

```
ruby setup.rb
```

But get a Permission denied error, so I try sudo:

```
sudo ruby setup.rb
```

But this gives me the error:

> sudo: ruby: command not found

Would anyone know what's going on here?

**Edit - more info**

I checked the version of ruby and its 2.3.0p0.

If I try to check the version of Gems is says to install Ruby 1.9.1.

I don't really understand this...

Answer (score 1):

`sudo` doesn't preserve your `$PATH` environment variable, so unless `ruby` is installed somewhere that's in *root*'s path, it's not going to be found.

Run `which ruby` to find out where ruby is installed, then `sudo /path/to/ruby setup.rb`

Also, more importantly, that's completely unnecessary. Those instructions are *old*. Rubygems has been built-in to ruby for a long time now. The site you linked even says, "If you’re on Ruby 1.9.*, then you don’t have to worry about installing Rubygems; it’s built in." If you're on 2.3.0, you don't need to install Rubygems, you have it already.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to you use RMV to install Ruby and Gem versions.

## Install RVM

### https://rvm.io/

```
- gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3
- \curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
- source /home/vagrant/.rvm/scripts/rvm
```

## Install Ruby

```
rvm get stable --autolibs=enable
rvm install ruby-2.3.1
```

## Use default ruby version

```
rvm --default use ruby-2.3.1
```